# Regexp not working with cURL url contents

Tags: php, regex, curl

In my code my `Regexp` works fine when I assign `html` content to variable but not working with `url path` . I am getting empty array.

```
    <?php 
    $productmfgno = "154637401";
                $url = "http://www.pandorasoem.com/search#q=".$productmfgno;
                $ch1= curl_init();
                curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
                curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
                curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)');
                curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://www.google.com');  //just a fake referer
                curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_POST,0);
                curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 20);
                $htmlContent= curl_exec($ch1);
                curl_close($ch1);
      /* It works when I assign this html content to $htmlContent variable but not working with cURL url

  $htmlContent = '<div class="findify-navigation-header findify-clearfix"> <div class="findify-pagination findify-push-right"></div> <div class="findify-header">Showing 2 results for <span class="findify-query">"154637401"</span>. <span id="findify-didyoumean"></span></div> </div>';

*/
                preg_match_all('/<div.*class=\"findify\-header\".*?>(.*?)<span.*class=\"findify-query\">.*?<\/div>/Us', $htmlContent, $count);
                print_r($count);
```

Expected Result - `Showing 2 results for`

So I can fetch that result count.

Comment: I am getting empty array.

Comment: http://www.pandorasoem.com/search#q=154637401 - this page source doesnt contain any html you mentioned, It is loading results by javascript

Comment: I see no `class="findify-query"` in `view-source:http://www.pandorasoem.com/search#q=154637401`

Comment: But I am getting content when echo $htmlContent variable.

Comment: Is there any other way to get that number

Comment: check s1lent1um answer , you gotta do curl for the javascript url

Comment: Ok Thank you everybody ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is, there are no results on the page, you're requesting. Actual search is performed via ajax after the page is loaded.

Ajax endpoint for the search, you might be looking for, returns result in javascript code (not json). There it is:

http://api.findify.io/v1.0/store/search?callback=jQuery111206735094679573879_1458022087824&q=154637401&key=5b31ee91-78fa-48e1-9338-1748ca55028e&analytics%5Bkey%5D=5b31ee91-78fa-48e1-9338-1748ca55028e&analytics%5Bvisit%5D=true&analytics%5Buniq%5D=true&analytics%5Burl%5D=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.pandorasoem.com%252Fsearch%2523q%253D154637401&analytics%5Bbaseurl%5D=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.pandorasoem.com%252Fsearch%2523q%253D154637401&analytics%5Bhost%5D=www.pandorasoem.com&analytics%5Bwidth%5D=1920&analytics%5Bheight%5D=1200&analytics%5Binner_width%5D=1438&analytics%5Binner_height%5D=667&analytics%5Bdoc_width%5D=1438&analytics%5Bdoc_height%5D=915&analytics%5Bscroll_x%5D=0&analytics%5Bscroll_y%5D=0&analytics%5Bvisit_id%5D=Ts22zuHHGJRZc3U1&analytics%5Buniq_id%5D=BoeCUKSzgdML6C50&byPage=24&page=0&_=1458022087825

**UPD**: As the format is different you'll need a new regular expression. Something like this will do:

```
preg_match_all('/["\']?totalHits["\']?\s*:\s*(\d+)/gi', $htmlContent, $count);
```

Comment: I was about to post it

Comment: So I need to apply `Regexp` to this url ? I want to fetch products count from search result. so I can fetch data to each products.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to apply a regex to this url. But you'll need to rewrite it (see **UPD**).

Comment: first it shows unknown modifier `g` error then after removing `g` from `regexp` it shows empty array. what is totalHits here ?

Comment: @s1lent1um What will be the `Regexp` to extract product urls on the same page